# How to copy folder and its content into new location in SharePoint Online with python office365 module

Tags: python, sharepoint-online, office365-rest-client

I am trying to copy a folder with all its content from one site to another in SharePoint Online. So I created a code that recursively creates the folder structure. 
What I can't do is to copy the files. For the start I am trying to test the following very simple code which I got from [GitHub](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/1c7e0be5ba6839f009b2e9ef86933b9fd3e9c383/examples/sharepoint/folders/copy_folder.pyhttps://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/1c7e0be5ba6839f009b2e9ef86933b9fd3e9c383/examples/sharepoint/folders/copy_folder.py)

```
url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MyTeam'
ctx = ClientContext(url).with_credentials(ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret))

source_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url('Shared Documents/from')    
target_folder = source_folder.copy_to('Shared Documents/to').get().execute_query()
```

This code doesn't do anything at all.
 I tried to check the paths and print out the files in the `source_folder` and `target_folder`. It prints out the files in the `source_folder` and prints nothing for the `target_folder`. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use sever relatice url like this：

`/sites/MyTeam/Shared Documents/from` and `/sites/MyTeam/Shared Documents/to`

Check if it works.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your answer, but it didn't help.